# conversion from `double' to non-scalar type requested and some other errors

Tags: c++

Please read my code, and help me to debug it. because `Dev-C++` finds a lot of errors....

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

struct iWorker{
       double salary;
}

double calSalary(iWorker worker){
    double money = worker.salary;
    return money;
}

int main(){
    iWorker worker;

    cout << "Enter salary: ";
    cin >> worker.salary;

    double salary = calSalary(worker, 0);
    cout << salary;

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

and errors:

```
9: error: new types may not be defined in a return type
9: error: two or more data types in declaration of `calSalary'
 In function `iWorker calSalary(iWorker)':
11: error: conversion from `double' to non-scalar type `iWorker' requested

 In function `int main()':
9: error: too many arguments to function `iWorker calSalary(iWorker)'
20: error: at this point in file
20: error: cannot convert `iWorker' to `double' in initialization
```

Thank you ...

Comment: `<iostream.h>` predates standardisation of C++ (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214230/iostream-vs-iostream-h-vs-iostream-h) - 1998!. Any new code definitely shouldn't be using it any books which use it are *horribly* outdated!

Comment: `calSalary` just take a single parameter. In your call to the function, why are you passing an extra parameter **0** to the function? Is it a typo ?

Comment: @Mahesh, yes, I want to check how functions work. (and i removed it)

Comment: Please, get rid of Dev-C++ as soon as you can. Read the [Dev-C++ tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dev-c%2b%2b/info).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, OK, i have installed Dev on my windows, in linux i have qt. but i should install it on windows too.

Comment: Did you grab a 10quick year old C++ book out of the garbage with a free Dev++ floppy in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a `;`  after your struct declaration:

```
struct iWorker{
   ...
};  // <- this one here
```

Answer (score 3):

```
struct iWorker{
       int id;
       char name[100];
       float hours;
       double salary;
} <--- missing semicolon here ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Damn, I was too late. But you also have a possible buffer overrun in this line:

```
cin >> worker.name;
```

Why don't you use `std::string`?