# include "file.h" vs <file> what is the difference?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, include

I'm working in Visual studio 2010. I Added a directory to  Project Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Directories

The project compiles if I use

```
 "file.h"
```

but not if i use

```
 <file>
```

Comment: Because `file.h` is a different name to `file`?

Comment: If `#include "filename"` fails to find the named file, it is implicitly changed to `#include <filename>` and retried with (possibly) different search options

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are probably assuming that `< >` implicitly adds `.h` to the end of the file name. This is not true. Whether you use `< >` or `" "` has no significance on the name of the file. It basically tells the implementation in which order it should traverse include directories to find the header file.

To quote the standard:

> A preprocessing directive of the form
> `# include <h-char-sequence> new-line`
> searches a sequence of implementation-deﬁned places for a header identified uniquely by the speciﬁed sequence between the `<` and `>` delimiters, and causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the header. How the places are speciﬁed or the header identiﬁed is implementation-deﬁned.
>
> A preprocessing directive of the form
> `# include "q-char-sequence" new-line`
> causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the source ﬁle identiﬁed by the specified sequence between the `"` delimiters. The named source ﬁle is searched for in an implementation-deﬁned manner. If this search is not supported, or if the search fails, the directive is reprocessed as if it read
>
> `# include <h-char-sequence> new-line`
> with the identical contained sequence (including `>` characters, if any) from the original directive

Comment: "…tells the _preprocessor_" :-P

Comment: @sidyll The technically correct term would be "the *implementation*". The standard does not specify whether or not preprocessing should be done by a separate program.

Comment: To complete this answer, it would be nice to also explain that <file.h> and <file> might not be the same file AND that standard library files provided by the compiler do not have extension. That way you can make the difference with other files that need to be in the include paths.

Comment: @Klaim Indeed. To further clarify, C standard library headers all have `.h` extension whereas C++ ones don't have any extension.

Comment: @Klaim: we even have an example: `<string>` is the C++ string-related stuff (`basic_string` & co.), while `<string.h>` is the legacy header for C string-handling functions.

Answer (score 5):

"" is for local files and <> are from files in the C library.

Comment: Almost correct - `""` will also include library files. But it's still a good general rule.

Answer (score 1):

An include works only if there is exists such a file.  In your case it might be cause there is a file **file.h** but note simply **file**.

You probably think it should work everywhere as you might have seen it with **iostream.h** and **iostream**.  [This is because they are two different files which mean two different things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214230/iostream-vs-iostream-h-vs-iostream-h).