# The difference between <> and "" in MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, include, crystal-space-3d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include “filename”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)
>   [include “file.h” vs <file> what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160089/include-file-h-vs-file-what-is-the-difference)

I've encountered this a couple of times when using external libraries and I assume that this is purely because of my inexperience. My question as the title says is what is the difference between using <> in an include and "", its clearly a big one as you can't include your own headers with <> but you can with "" and vice versa you can't include headers such as `<string>` with "".

I'm using the Crystal Space SDK at the moment and I'm working my way through getting to grips with it and following the tutorials. I was following the Creating-External-MSVC-Application Howto guide and encountered this error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: NewDawn, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  simple1.cpp
1>f:\project\newdawn\newdawn\include\cs\csplatform.h(26): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'csutil/win32/csconfig-msvc.h': No such file or directory
1>  main.cpp
1>f:\project\newdawn\newdawn\include\cs\csplatform.h(26): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'csutil/win32/csconfig-msvc.h': No such file or directory
1>  Generating Code...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I went and found the file csplatform.h and found that it included the file csconfig-msvc.h  using < >:

```
#if defined (CS_WIN32_CSCONFIG)
/* Use manually maintained settings when not building on environments not
* using configure (specifically, MSVC) */
#  include <csutil/win32/csconfig-msvc.h>
#else
#  include <csconfig.h>
#endif
```

I could theoretically change the #include csutil/win32/csconfig-msvc.h from < > to " " but I shouldn't have to do that, this is a well established Code Library and the simplest tutorial should work straight out the box.

I want to know why it does it with < > and not " ". I seen Boost do it as well if I remember right.

Comment: [include “file.h” vs <file> what is the difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160089/include-file-h-vs-file-what-is-the-difference) Are your include paths set up correctly?

Comment: Add path to Crystal Space SDK include files into your projects include  paths.

Comment: I believe the include paths are correct, I have the /include folder in the VC++ Directories Include Directories field.

Comment: Did not find that in my searches. Apologises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#include <some file>` uses the include search path. `#include "some file"` is relative to the file being compiled. So if you want  to use `#include <some file>` you need to modify the include search path.

Comment: As specified by the standard, if #include "some file" fails, it falls back to try #include <some file>. Hence #include "windows.h" will succeed.

Comment: And how do you modify the include search path?

Comment: In the compiler settings in your project configuration.

Comment: Both version search a list of paths. The list of paths is different for each version. The "" version will fall back to <> versions list of paths if it fails. As a result <> usually indicates system includes; while "" usually indicates local includes.