# Visual Studio 2015 c++ cannot open include file or source files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

[image]I was using Visual Studio before I updated last version. Now, I cannot even run a simple hello world program. Because I am not familliar with Visual Studio much, I have no idea what to do. This is the error it gives me.
[image]

Comment: can you show the contents of stdafx.h and output window too?

Comment: I edited the picture, you can look at @Asesh

Answer (score 0):

Open an empty project.

Inside the Solution explorer, right click on source files folder ,and click new source file.

You can name it main.cpp.

After that write your main function inside main.cpp.

Compile and Run with F5.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31736361/visual-studio-2015-gives-me-errors-upon-creating-a-simple-test-console-program

Comment: Looks like you might have to reinstall Visual Studio. Code looks fine to me

Answer (score 0):

This Sounds like corrupt vc++-paths 
Try clearing all variables in the projectproperties category "vc++-paths" so the defaults will be used.

For more information see
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855621.aspx

Comment: I tried it but it still gives me the same error.It says it cannot open include file "stdio.h" no such file or directory. I searched through the all problems here and still could not find a solution yet but people easily could give - points for my effort

Comment: Have you tried restarting Visual Studio? Restarting your PC?