# Undeclared identifier in limits header in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

While compiling my project which seems extremely primitive

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  std::cout << 1;
  return 0;
}
```

I get many similar errors like

> E0020  identifier "FLT_RADIX" is undefined smo c:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.24930\include\limits    201

and

> E0020  identifier "FLT_MIN" is undefined   smo c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.24930\include\limits    1084

All errors refer to the **limits** file. It might be a problem with references to C libs as was mentioned here
[Visual studio 2015 gives me errors upon creating a simple test console program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31736361/visual-studio-2015-gives-me-errors-upon-creating-a-simple-test-console-program)
but defining the path to the libs from Windows Kits explicitly didn't solve the problem.