# Console cpp project in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, download, ide

What and how should I install in order to be able to create an ordinary console project in Visual Studio?

Here is what I have already installed and what options I have. The problem is that there is no option for creating an ordinary console project. Is it named somewhat different not just a console project in cpp?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look under the "Installed" tab on the left side, not the "Online" tab you currently selected. You should find "Win32 Console Application" there.

Comment: It helped out. Revert your answer.

Comment: I was a bit hesitating with the answer because your second screenshot shows the "Installed" tab, correctly. Anyway, I'm glad that I helped :)

Comment: Now I got a new problem `cannot open source file "stdio.h", "tchar.h"`. ) :

Comment: Found an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31736361/visual-studio-2015-gives-me-errors-upon-creating-a-simple-test-console-program, but it seems pretty hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use **'Empty project'** option for such purposes. Just type 'Empty' in the search field to find it.

In this case you have to manually add `.cpp` file, define a `main` function - and you will have simple console application with no Windows-specific overheads.