# can't find C headers after updating to vs2017 15.2

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, header-files

I updated my VS2017 to 15.2 Community Edition, but now the previous project that is actually developed in VS2017 now not compiling, it can't able to find any c headers and I can't use c++ counterparts{ c* }because I had to make it compile on some really old compilers like Turbo C++ and I want to change as less as much as I can when I ready them to compile on older compilers

Comment: when you updated did you make sure to install the SDK update?

Comment: i have installed every sdk i can found but letmme check again

Comment: Wasn't there a separate C runtime and header part in the installer?

Comment: sorry, but I can't find it, there is "C++/CLI Support"

Comment: "had to make it compile on some really old compilers like Turbo C++" - painful that. *Why*?

Comment: my school still uses Turbo C++, but i enjoy the comfort of autocompletion and other fancy things like very good debugger( turbo don't have it )

Comment: Turbo C++ was dead before I got into C++, but Borland's debugger for Turbo C was actually pretty good. How it compares to the tools available today is lost to aged blur, but for it's time, it rocked.

Comment: sorry but I haven't even try that

Comment: Don't worry about it. Stick with using the new stuff. Learning to use 30 year old tools should only be done if you have a very strong business case for it. In your case it's great to see you tempering a requirement to learn obsolescence with learning to use the stuff you're likely to see and use in a career today. Puts you several steps ahead of your fellow students when you hit the job market.

Comment: Maybe add the native C/C++ support?  C++/CLI is .Net.

Comment: Is this answer of any use to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43019759/4581301 ?

Comment: sir i have all of them, i am repairing it let see what happens next

Comment: This may also be useful: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24354/cant-compile-vs2015-project-in-vs2017-missing-c-in.html

Comment: thanks but it's taking toooo long to repair, I will read them until then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cfa48739-cd32-43d2-9d27-2b6653da6645/canf-find-standard-c-header-file-in-visual-studio-2015-community-version?forum=vclanguage) from MSDN forums sheds some light on the matter. I'll quote one of the answers there:

> The C runtime has become a OS component and its headers and libraries are now part of the Windows SDK instead of VC++. I don't have a machine with VS2015 handy to check the exact paths but search for them in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits. If you can't find there then something went wrong during VS install.

You can find some details [in this announce](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/) from Microsoft.

Section "Building Software using the Universal CRT" states:

> Previously, all of the CRT headers, sources, and libraries were distributed as part of the Visual C++ SDK, installed in the VC subdirectory of your Visual Studio installation (generally C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC). The files for the VCRuntime are still part of the Visual C++ SDK. The headers, sources, and libraries are now distributed as part of a separate Universal CRT SDK. This SDK is included with Visual Studio; it is installed by default to C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10.

Comment: Yep, I installed windows 8 and 10 sdk, and it's working now