# Why my coding got error cannot convert int to int * in function main ?

Tags: c++, arrays, int

```
#include<iostream.h>
void main()
{
    int i[10], sum, n1, n2, size;

    cout<<"Enter size array :";
    cin>>size;

    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
      cout<<"Enter number 1 :";
      cin>>n1[i];
      cout<<"Enter number 2 :";
      cin>>n2[i];
      sum[i]=n1[i]+n2[i];
    }

    cout<<"sum : "<<sum;
}
```

i have no idea. please help me . it also stated there Lvalue required in function main.

Comment: `n1` is an `int` and you're trying to index it. Also worth noting `<iostream.h>` isn't a standard header and it should be `int main`.

Comment: sum, n1 and n2 are not arrays. Also, are you using Turbo C++?

Comment: related concerning [iostream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214230/iostream-vs-iostream-h-vs-iostream-h) and concerning [type returned by main](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214230/iostream-vs-iostream-h-vs-iostream-h) (look at the bold part of the answer) if you want to know more about what chris meant

Comment: @remyabel _'Turbo C++'_ **Brrrr! Choke! Cough!!!**  (`#include<iostream.h>` is a pretty good indicator) Why do we see this so often here (especially from beginner students)?? Is there a major problem migrating university personal to nowadays compiler standards??

Comment: im a beginner. oh i get it. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to try this:

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    int i, sum[10], n1[10], n2[10], size;

    cout<<"Enter size array :";
    cin>>size;

    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
      cout<<"Enter number 1 :";
      cin>>n1[i];
      cout<<"Enter number 2 :";
      cin>>n2[i];
      sum[i]=n1[i]+n2[i];

    cout<<"sum : "<<sum[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int i[10], sum, n1, n2, size;
```

You declare `i` to be an array, but you use it like it's a single value. You try to index `sum`, `n1`, and `n2` by writing `[i]` after them in the loop, but they're not declared as arrays.

Recommendation: change your variable declarations.

```
int i, sum[10], n1[10], n2[10], size;
```

Comment: yes im using turbo c++