# Is this a difference between iostream.h and iostream

Tags: c++, syntax, include, language-lawyer

I am aware that questions about the difference between `<header>` and `<header.h>` have been asked before. And after reading those answers, I have enlisted the following differences

- Of course `iostream.h` is deprecated, it is not supported by newer standard-complying compilers
- `iostream.h`doesn't contain everything inside the `std` namespace and doesn't make use of templates.

Okay.

But, after reading a few books and a few answers (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19719687/2243767)), I have inferred that `#include<iostream.h>` includes a **specific file called iostream.h** in our program whereas, `#include<iostream>` is NOT even required to map to a file at all. It simply guarantees that everything belonging to the `iostream` library is included in our program. Am I correct?

Comment: A 16 year old C++ compiler that properly implements the C++ standard is not "newer".  You'll need to find better books.

Comment: @HansPassant Please don't go so literally. You know what I mean. We don't even need to use `iostream.h` anyway. But unfortunately, I have a bad teacher who is stuck in the 1990s and he keeps on raising such things all the time.

Comment: I am not perfectly sure at the moment, so I'm writing this as comment: seems ok to be. I can imagine a compiler that keeps all stdlibs in huge ZIP file and looks up there. I really doubt it'd be marked as violating the standard due to such thing.

Comment: Ah and one more thing: you are wrong in syntax: the "include specific file (from 'project')" is `#include "fooofile"` and "include wellknown library" is `#include <foofile>`.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Oh, thanks. That's a good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No "system" header is required to be a file. Inclusion using `<>` is specified thusly:

> C++11 16.2 [cpp.include]/2: searches a sequence of implementation-defined places for a header identified uniquely by the specified sequence between the < and > delimiters, and causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the header. How the places are specified or the header identified is implementation-defined.

So the declarations from headers known to the implementation (which might or might not include current and/or obsolete standard library headers) can be made available without loading and preprocessing a text file, if the implementor deems that to be a good idea.

Including with `""` will first search for a file (in implementation-defined places), and fall back to `<>` if that fails.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. +1 :) Well, do you mean that even including `iostream.h` doesn't necessarily mean that there is a file called iostream.h which I am including in my program?

Comment: @ThePeacefulCoder: Indeed, there's no requirement for anything included with `<>` to be in a file, as long as the compiler has some other way to provide its declarations.

Comment: Okay. I see. Then, except the first two differences (the ones I enlisted) there is absolutely no difference between <header.h> and <header>. Isn't it?

Comment: I wonder if any implementation provides a way to pull a file off the net. Like `-Ihttp://abcd.com/g++/include`

Comment: @ThePeacefulCoder: Not as far as the standard's concerned. Any particular compiler might treat them differently, depending on its implementation-defined rules for finding headers.