# Fatal Error in c++ while using local variables

Tags: c++, iostream

As am learning cpp tutorial

```
#include <iostream.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //variable declaration
    int a,b;
    int c;

    //actual initialization
    a=10;b=20;
    c=a+b;

    cout<<c;
    return 0;
}
```

my error

```
fatal error: iostream.h
```

Comment: If the tutorial is telling you to use `<iostream.h>`, it's aimed at C++ as it was 20 years ago, before it was even standardized.

Comment: [Step 1] Replace `iostream.h` with `iostream`, [step 2] Switch to some updated tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Just change `<iostream.h>` to `<iostream>`

Reason is that .h header extensions were used for **C** includes but aren't used for **C++** anymore.

In fact, you can actually use **C** libraries with .h it's just there isn't one for **iostream** since its **C++** exclusive, hence the fatal error.

Comment: can you explain why it should be changed as like

Comment: @reenadevi the tutorial you're using is giving instruction on the C++ language as it was before formal standardization. See this question : ["<iostream> vs. <iostream.h> vs. “iostream.h”"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214230/iostream-vs-iostream-h-vs-iostream-h). I *strongly* advise you get another tutorial.