# why do we use "using namespace std" ? Can we use #include<conio.h> instead?

Tags: c++, std

I am really confused about how we use std libraries in the header. When to use which library. Is **"using namespace std"** and **conio.h** different..?? Or are they the same thing. And what is the difference between **"iostream"** and **"iostream.h"**. These things are making me really confused.....

Comment: If you're confused, then make things simple: stop writing `using namespace std`.

Comment: Where do you find this dark age stuff?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [<iostream> vs. <iostream.h> vs. "iostream.h"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214230/iostream-vs-iostream-h-vs-iostream-h)

Answer (score 1):

1. `std` is the namespace for the C++ standard library - for example, `string` actually belongs to this namespace, so the full name for `string` is `std::string`. `using namespace std` tells the compiler that we want to access the resources in this namespace - giving us `global`, or direct access to the `string` it holds. Take a look at Pete's comment for more details.
2. The C++ standard library contains many different packages that can be included by their headers, one of which is `<iostream>`, more `std` headers can be found here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/
3. `conio.h` looks like an older DOS-specific C header that is not popular anymore.
4. `iostream.h` was renamed to `iostream` as a standard at some point: http://members.gamedev.net/sicrane/articles/iostream.html

Also see: [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Edits thanks to Pete!

Comment: `using namespace std;` doesn't "tell the compiler which `string` we're using"; it tells the compiler to, essentially, treat **all** names that are defined in `std` as if they were also defined in the global namespace. You could define your own name `string` in the global namespace, and `using namespace std;` would then guarantee that whenever you referred to `string` it would be ambiguous. That aside, good answer.

Comment: Incidentally, `conio.h` comes from DOS, not Windows. <g>

Comment: Good distinctions to point out, thanks! will edit

Answer (score 0):

It just simply allows you to **use** the **namespace** `std`, which is the namespace of most standard C++ header libraries. If you use it, you won't have to put the `std::` prefix on accessing, for example, `std::cout` or `std::cin`, which would now be just `cout` and `cin` respectively.

For example:

```
// without using namespace std
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World"; // error
    std::cout << "Hello World"; // outputs Hello World
    return 0;
}
```

Now with `using namespace std`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World"; // outputs Hello World
    return 0;
}
```

`conio.h` is a C++ library that contains functions such as `getch()` and `putch()`. `iostream.h` is a **pre-standard** C++ library that was used before namespaces were introduced. `iostream` is a standard library that contains objects such as `cin` and `cout`.